# How do I get only a certain value in a text file to a combo box?

Tags: c#, combobox

so I need help regarding how do I add only a certain info to a combo box. My groupmates and I are making a dog pound program where you can buy a dog or donate a dog (Not a real dog pound, btw. Just created for fun). So when a user decides to buy a dog he/she can choose a breed from the combo box(that was successfully made, btw). Then, the user clicks the next button so that the user can pick one from the list inside the combo box (problem is, the items for the combo box will be getting from the text file).

So for example, the user chooses a bulldog as a breed then clicks "next". Then the next window will show a combo box that lists all dogs that are bulldogs inside the text file (tag number of the dog -int-, name of the dog -string- and price -decimal-)

the text file goes like this:

```
1-Chihuahua+YY=625.00
3-Boxer+Rad=875.00
25-Terrier+Micky=1500.00
10-Bulldog+Mary=1997.500
4-Pug+Charlie=562.50
6-Bulldog+Cayne=2062.50
```

*(tagNumber-Breed+nameOfTheDog=Price)
**one dog info = one line, don't know what happened with the structure of the text

and the code so far goes like this:

```
  string location=@"C:\\Users\\LMCPENA98\\Desktop\\MilleniumPaws\\bin\\Debug\\Files.txt";
        string[] temp = File.ReadAllLines(location);
        int[] TagNumber = new int[temp.Length];
        string[] Breed = new string[temp.Length];
        string[] Name = new string[temp.Length];
        decimal[] Price = new decimal[temp.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < TagNumber.Length; i++)
        {
            TagNumber[i] = int.Parse(temp[i].Substring(0, temp[i].IndexOf("-")));
            Breed[i] = temp[i].Substring(0, temp[i].IndexOf("+"));
            Breed[i] = Breed[i].Substring(Breed[i].LastIndexOf("-") + 1);
            Name[i] = temp[i].Substring(0, temp[i].IndexOf("="));
            Name[i] = Name[i].Substring(Name[i].LastIndexOf("+") + 1);
            Price[i] = decimal.Parse(temp[i].Substring(temp[i].LastIndexOf("=") + 1));
```

How can I display only the two bulldogs named Mary and Cayne into the combo box (tag number and price included)??

Comment: try reading the lines in the textfile into a String[] from there you could use then you could use the SubString or IndexOf method you could use the .Contains method as well.. try to see if there is a pattern to the textfile layout and create a Class that mimics the file structure and work with it that way..

Answer (score 1):

First, obtain the data in the *most convenient* format:

```
  var data = File
    .ReadLines(location)  
    .Select(line => Split('-', '+', '='))
    .Select(items => new {
       tagNumber = int.Parse(items[0]),
       breed = items[1], 
       name = items[2], 
       price = Decimal.Parse(items[3])
     });
```

then filter out and represent

```
  myComboBox.Items.AddRange(data
    .Where(item => (item.breed == "Bulldog") &&
                   ((item.name == "Mary") || (item.name == "Cayne"))))
    .Select(item => String.Format("tag: {0}; price: {1}", item.tagNumber, item.price)));
```

I've used an *anonymous class*, but if such queries are frequent, you may want to implement a special class for record in the file:

```
 public class Dog {
   public int TagNumber {get; private set}
   ...
   public decimal Price {get; private set}
   ...
   public static Dog Parse(String value) {...}
   ...
   public override String ToString() {
     return String.Fromat("tag: {0}; price: {1}", TagNumber, Price);  
   }
 } 


 var data = File
   .ReadLines(location) 
   .Select(line => Dog.Parse(line));

 ...
 myComboBox.Items.AddRange(data
   .Where(dog => (dog.Breed == "Bulldog") &&
                 ((dog.Name == "Mary") || (dog.Name == "Cayne"))))
   .Select(dog => dog.ToString()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if (Breed[i] == BreedChosen)
{
    TagNumber[i] = int.Parse(temp[i].Substring(0, temp[i].IndexOf("-")));
    Breed[i] = temp[i].Substring(0, temp[i].IndexOf("+"));
    Breed[i] = Breed[i].Substring(Breed[i].LastIndexOf("-") + 1);
    Name[i] = temp[i].Substring(0, temp[i].IndexOf("="));
    Name[i] = Name[i].Substring(Name[i].LastIndexOf("+") + 1);
    Price[i] = decimal.Parse(temp[i].Substring(temp[i].LastIndexOf("=") + 1));
}
```

... unless I've misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a whole restructuring of the code. It would be best if you create a class to hold all the data for your dogs, sth like:

```
public class Dog
    {
        public int tagNumber;
        public string Breed;
        public string Name;
        public decimal Price;

        public Dog()
        {
            tagNumber = 0;
            Breed = "None";
            Name = "Nameless";
            Price = 0;
        }
    }
```

You can add whatever kind of functionality you want in such a constructor, it's quite suitable for your needs and easy to work with.
Then you can load your dogs into a simple list and sort the data however you like. Example:

```
string location=@"C:\\Users\\LMCPENA98\\Desktop\\MilleniumPaws\\bin\\Debug\\Files.txt";
        string[] temp = File.ReadAllLines(location);

        //Now we'll get all the dogs from our text file
        List<Dog> listOfDogs =  temp
                                .Select(line => line.Split('-', '+', '='))//selecting an array of arrays with the parts of each line
                                .Select(parts => new Dog{   tagNumber = int.Parse(parts[0]),
                                                            Breed = parts[1],
                                                            Name = parts[2],
                                                            Price = Decimal.Parse(parts[3])})//we're converting those arrays of parts to an instance of our Dog class
                                .ToList();//making it list

        //Now you have your list of dogs

        //You can get all the breeds (if you need them for a combobox e.g.). Will be using hashset, so that all the equal strings would be gone
        HashSet<string> hsOfDogBreeds = new HashSet<string>(listOfDogs.Select(dog => dog.Breed));

        //Afterwards you can do quite much everything you want with the info and it's more comfortable in this way.
```